# Cвязи между таблицами.  Как добавить в одну таблицу данные из другой

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать код.
Есть две таблицы, как сделать так чтобы `order_id` из таблицы `orders`, добавлялся в таблицу `prod_order`. Надеюсь на любую помощь.

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `s_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `post_index` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `data` date NOT NULL,
 `time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=96 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=96 ;
  ---
CREATE TABLE `prod_order` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `product` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
 `gty` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=140 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=140 ;

<?
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id=$_GET['id'];}
    if($_SESSION['cart'] && !isset($_POST['order']))
    {
?>
<form action="index.php?view=order" method="post" id="cart-form">
<table id="mycart" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tr>
       <th>Товар</th>
       <th>Цена</th>
       <th>Кол-во</th>
       <th>Всего</th>
      </tr> 
  <? foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity):
     $product = get_product($id);
  ?> 
   <tr>
      <td align="center"><?=$product['title'];?></td>
      <td align="center"><?=number_format($product['price'],2);?> руб.</td>
      <td align="center"><?=$quantity;?></td>
      <td align="center"><?=number_format($product['price'] * $quantity ,2);?> руб.</td>
      </tr>  
    <? endforeach;?>
  </table> 
    <p align="center">Общая сумма заказа: <span class="product-price"><?=number_format($_SESSION['total_price'],2);?> руб.</span></p>
   <br>
    <p align="center"><strong>Для оформления заказа введите данные:</strong></p>
    <p align="center">
     Ваше Имя:      <input type="text" name="name" />     Ваша Фамилия:      <input type="text" name="s_name" />     Ваш адрес:      <input type="text" name="address" />       Почтовый индекс:      <input type="text" name="post_index" />     Ваш e-mail:      <input type="text" name="email" />  </p>
        <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="order" value="Заказать" /></p>
    </form>
   <br><br>
```

---

```
 <?
    }
    if($_SESSION['cart'] && isset($_POST['order']))
     {    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
$s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$post_index = $_POST['post_index'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');          
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `orders`(name,s_name,address,post_index,email,data,time) VALUES ('$name','$s_name','$address','$post_index','$email','$date','$time')");    
$result = mysql_insert_id("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(order_id) FROM `orders`"); 
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity):
$product = get_product($id);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `prod_order`(order_id,prod_id,product,price,gty) VALUES ('$order_id','{$product['id']}','{$product['title']}','{$product['price']}','$quantity')");
endforeach; 
echo "<p align='center'>Ваш заказ успешно принят! Спасибо за покупку!</p>";
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

делаете инсерт в таблицу orders, потом ловите last_insert_id через [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-insert-id), и циклом добавляете в таблицу prod_order соответствия каждого продукта и этого last_insert_id

Comment: @mountpoint, для особо "одаренных",вроде меня, можно поподробнее, пожалуйста?
Вот это так?
$result = mysql_insert_id("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(order_id) FROM `orders`");

Comment: у вас в инсерте есть $order_id. Откуда оно берется? Это первое. Второе - $result = mysql_insert_id(); вот так. Возможно вместо $order_id нужно поставить $result ??

Comment: @mountpoint, о чудо! Все работает! Огромная Вам благодарность!!!