# Как правильно вставить заказ и товары заказа в таблицу

Tags: mysql, интернет-магазин

Здравствуйте, есть массив с товарами, которые пользователь кинул в корзину. После нажатия на кнопку отправить, мы делаем запись в таблицу orders, следующего типа:

'','дата и время','логин'.

Первый столбец id `A_I`. То есть мы получили новый заказ "id" на пользователя "логин". Теперь вставляем в orders_goods

```
'','id_product','price','kolichestvo','nomer_zakaza=id с первой таблицы'.
```

Я не могу понять как связать id из первой таблицы с nomer_zakaza со второй, ведь они вставляются одновременно и он `A_I`? Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'kolichestvo' - 'quantity'

Вот тут посмотрите: [Cвязи между таблицами. Как добавить в одну таблицу данные из другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/272366/php-c%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Немного коряво, но суть поймете

Comment: spasibo bolshoe